# Directive using $compile leads to browser memory error

Tags: angularjs

Using this directive to add some popover attributes to an element. The problem is the excessive use of `$compile` which leads to the browser not responsing anymore or an maximum memory usage error. I am using this directive on around 50 elements on 1 page.

### Question

How to improve the performance of my directive? Is there any other way to handle the creation and manipulation of attributes on my directive?

### Html

```
<span trim-to-tooltip="transaction.devicehash"></span>
```

### Directive

```
angular.module('app.xxx').directive('trimToTooltip', [
'$timeout', '$compile',
function ($timeout, $compile) {

return {
  link: link,
  restrict: 'AE'
};

function link($scope, $element, $attrs) {
  var maxLength = 18;
  var originalValue, trimmedValue;

  function _init() {
    $scope.$watch($attrs.trimToTooltip, function (v, o) {
      if (!o && v === o)
        return;
      originalValue = v;

      if (originalValue.length - 3 > maxLength) {
        trimmedValue = originalValue.substring(0, maxLength) + '...';

        if (!$element.attr('popover')) {
          $element.attr('popover', originalValue);
          $element.attr('popover-placement', 'top');
          $element.attr('popover-trigger', 'click');

          $compile($element)($scope);
        }
      } else {
        $element.removeAttr('popover');
        $element.removeAttr('popover-placement');
        $element.removeAttr('popover-trigger');

        $compile($element)($scope);
      }

      $element.text(trimmedValue);
    });
  }

  _init();
  }}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you remove `trim-to-tooltip` attribute before you compile element, otherwise you basically recompile `trimToTooltip` directive all over again, which can lead to infinite loop and cause troubles:

```
$element.removeAttr('trim-to-tooltip');
$compile($element)($scope);
```

Comment: Thanks. But the model `transaction.devicehash` passed to my directive will change often, and I need to execute the directive again. Will the code execute after removing the attribute? If yes, where should I place your code?

Comment: Even though the attribute is removed, the tooltip of the old model value is being shown. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can make directive just with template like:

```
<span ng-if="str.length > 18" popover=...>{{str | substr:18}}</span>
<span ng-if="str.length < 18">{{str}}</span>
```

Comment: Yes possible but imagine having 200 spans in my code... I do not want to edit all my html.

Comment: I mean  your trim-to-tooltip directive may contain more or less this template.

Comment: How would I watch my model for changes then?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/I4cunYgspMRwvTtXjGzm?p=preview you do not need create any watchers manually in this case

Comment: Thanks but I cannot use scope since popover is asking for isolated scope already...

Comment: Is there another solution without using an isolated scope on my directive?

Comment: you can use isolated scope (Updated plunk with 2nd directive)- popover is on another element in this case. If one day you cannot - then you need to parse attrs manually and add watch.